# Intuition behind $O_\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \neq \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, intuition

What's the intuition behind the fact that we don't always have the equality $O_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)} = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ ? As in, from where the ``extra" algebraic numbers which somehow happens to be algebraic integers are coming from ?

Same question for the fact that why we don't always have $O_{KL} \neq O_K \times O_L$ (where $[L:\mathbb{Q}] = [KL:L]$), and why you're expected to have an ``extra" family of algebraic integers in $O_{KL}$ that are not in $O_K \times O_L$ ?

I do know examples of the above (for the first line, $\alpha$ being a root of $x^3+x^2-2x-8 =0$, and for the second case taking $K = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}], L = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$ works (we get an ``extra" family of algebraic integers $\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{2}$ in $O_{KL}$, and that's because we have the identity $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{2}$, which to me is quite surprising and/or coincidental)), but I don't have any intuition as why such things are happening, and whether this event is the exception or the norm.

I would think that $O_{\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]} \neq \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is an exception, since taking the minimal polynomial of any element $z = \sum a_k \alpha^k$ in $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and needing them to be integers AND in order for $z \not \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ requires $a_k$'s satisfying some very rigid set of equation.

Comment: This is a rather common situation, and it happens essentially because either $\alpha$ or some polynomial in it can have "unexpected divisibilities". For instance, suppose you consider the polynomial $x^2+9$. Its root is $\alpha=\sqrt{-9}=3i$, so $\mathbb Z[\alpha]=\mathbb Z[3i]$. Of course when I write it like that it's pretty clear that $3i$ "should" be a multiple of $3$ (though it's not in $\mathbb Z[3i]$, since the latter doesn't contain $i$. In many cases the divisibilities like less trivial, like the fact $\sqrt{5}+1$ "should" be divisible by $2$, but hopefully this sheds some light.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Not really, since $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha] = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{D}]$, we do have $O_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)} = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$

Comment: @katana_0 Based on these comments, maybe your question is unclear. Are you really trying to ask why $\mathcal O_K$ is not always  of the form $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ for *any* $\alpha$? Fields $K$ with $\mathcal O_K = \mathbb Z[\alpha]$ are called monogenic. You should note that most number fields are *not* monogenic, so that being monogenic is in fact the exception.

Comment: I guess here's a different way of viewing it. Why would you expect $\mathcal O_K$ to have a basis of the form $1, \alpha, \alpha^2,\ldots, \alpha^{n-1}$ for some $\alpha$? That seems like a very strong property!

Comment: Isn't it true for cyclotomic fields?

Comment: [Correct](https://mathoverflow.net/q/17289/15503), @J.W.Tanner. IIRC relatively easy in the prime power case, but not too trivial in the general case.